# How to change database OR connect to multiple databases with the same Bookshelf instance?

Tags: knex.js, bookshelf.js

Given the convention of initiating a single bookshelf instance per application [example below], how should one go about changing the database [use case below]?

or is the only possible workaround to initiate multiple bookshelf instance with different connection to multiple databases at the same time?

### Use Case

For example, a simple CMS app which is use to deliver several blogs. All the blogs and everything follows the same architecture, have the same models and etc, only the subdomain/directory and respective to that the database differs.

As often it is the case, the Bookshelf instance is initiated before the request is processed by the application, hence, it is required to dynamically set/alter the database while maintaining the rest of connection credentials.

### Typical Setup

in `app.js`

```
 module.exports = {
        'database': {
            mysql: {
                client: 'mysql',
                connection: {
                    host     : 'localhost',
                    user     : 'root',
                    password : '',
                    database : 'db',
                    charset  : 'utf8'
              }
          }
       }
    };
```

in `bookshelf.js`

```
const config = require('./app.js');
const knex = require('knex')(config.database.mysql);

module.exports = require('bookshelf')(knex);
```